# How to open Microsoft Office documents in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I do not want any code but want to get reference that how can we open Microsoft Office documents in our iPhone application.

Is there any way to edit this documents in iPhone?

I just want to know Is this possible or not?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display MS Office documents using `UIWebView` but editing is not possible (at least not without major effort).

Comment: Is there any link for that to open documents in UIWebview?

Comment: Currently I had gone through http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

Comment: I guess that's the best documentation available on this topic.

Comment: does this still apply? isn't there a way to edit the office file?

Comment: Yes, this still applies on iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying: instead of using UIWebView to display the office document, I found the UIDocumentInteractionController supports more formats than UIWebView(for example: docx) while also provides better performance. Plus it has built in interaction menu that allows you to share this document through Email or other 3rd part apps like dropbox.
One example of this controller is the built in Email app, which uses UIDocumentInterActionController to display attached files.

Apple's document regards to UIDocumentInterActionController
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html

How to use:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/previewing-and-opening-documents-with-uidocumentinteractioncontroller/

Editing: Sorry I can't help you with this one.